# Tailor in Hanoi, Vietnam

Tags: vietnam, services, hanoi

I will be traveling through Vietnam, and I'm looking to get some tailored shirts.
Unfortunately, the only place I'll have enough days in one place is Hanoi, so I'd like to do that there (I've read there are many wonderful tailors throughout the rest of Vietnam).

Where can one get tailored clothing made in a few days in Hanoi?

Answer (score 5):

A [blog on the topic of tailors in various cities in Vietnam](http://en.vietnamitasenmadrid.com/2012/03/tailor-made-clothing-in-vietnam.html), says that for Hanoi:

> As a recommendation to make a suit to measure in Hanoi, the best
>   tailor and the best store is Cao Minh. Cao Minh also tailoring shop in
>   Hanoi, also owns two shops in Ho Chi Minh City. Cao Minh Hanoi is
>   located at 250 Hang Bong Street (a few blocks south of the lake of
>   Hanoi). Cao Minh also has online shop, but do not buy a tailor-made
>   suit online unless they have made us one previously and we have the
>   exact measurements.

A lengthy review on the topic on [TripAdvisor](http://www.tripadvisor.com.au/ShowTopic-g293924-i8595-k4035865-Hanoi_tailor_recommendations-Hanoi.html) suggests:

> Bambou Silk
>
> 8 Nha Chung
>
> It's in the Old Quarter, near the cathedral.
>
> ¬¬¬¬¬¬
>
> Another shop he got a good suit from (also in the Old Quarter) was:
>
> Duc Minh
>
> 24 Hang Da

(I've trimmed snippets out of the lengthy review, for more detail click the link and have a read - they provide good descriptions of both)

Comment: I only checked out Cao Minh, to anyone wondering their prices were about $100 US for a shirt.

Comment: Wow 100$ is simply too expensive. For a shirt I don't think it's higher than 500kVND (~25USD)

Answer (score 3):

To add to Mark's recommendations, I had two shirts made at [Binh Minh](http://www.binhminhtailor.com/) tailor (warning: flash-heavy website with music!). The shirts came out very nice, and the cost was about $50 US per shirt (depending on the fabric).

Answer (score 0):

I often do it at Duc Nhuan 37 Hang Dau, the price depends on the fabric material, but the cost now for tailored shirts is about from 15$ to 20$, if you want to get it back soonest, please pay some extra.

You also can do it at: Duc Class - 73 Nguyen Huan

Answer (score 0):

the location 77 Hang Bong - Hoan Kiem - Hanoi, Cazo Bespoke tailoring, suits cost from 200$ - 300$ - 400$ they have a team and a comfortable space for you to enjoy and lie down. right on the center street, they can answer every request, especially they have a design with your own measurements, in the future you can order again from them, they will send it to you anywhere.